# BizTalk Binding import Error

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

Im New to the BizTalk while Importing the Binding files(XML) from some other server to local server it shows the following error,

### TITLE: Import Bindings

> Failed to update binding information. (mscorlib)
>
> ---
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Cannot update send port "sndPortNameSpcified". (Microsoft.BizTalk.Deployment)
>
> ---
>
> Cannot set send port "sndPortNameSpcified" send pipeline. Send pipeline "Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.PassThruTransmit, Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=dfcb6b17c9ded6e5" not found. (Microsoft.BizTalk.Deployment)

---

Before Importing i have replaced local public key token value and all the Location to the proper local structure, for SQL updated the Server credentials.

[image]

The specific error occurs in all the send ports in the application.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Why did you update the public keys tokens? I've never had to do that.  Those are what is uses to find the correct DLL's in the GAC.

Answer (score 1):

Open the VisualStudio Developer command prompt.

Type the following command:

```
gacutil /l | find "Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines"
```

Check the output against your configuration line.  On my machine (MS BizTalk Server 2013 enterprise), the public key token is different from what you have there:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0>gacutil /l | find "Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines"
>
> Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL

Why did you change it?  It should not ordinarily change from one installation of BizTalk to another (it's a public signature token the assembly uses to ensure that you're actually getting the right assembly, not just one with a similar name).

Your worst case scenario could just be to remove that send port from the bindings file, import the bindings, add the send port back using the Administration Console, and export the new bindings.  Alternatively, just add a send port to BizTalk Application 1, export the bindings, and compare the two sections.  Search your bindings file for the string "sndPortNameSpecified" to find the correct send port.  You'll be looking for a tag that starts with:

```
<SendPort Name="sndPortNameSpecified" IsStatic=....>
  <Description ... />
  ...
</SendPort>
```

If you do remove it, remove all other references to it as well, which would be tags that look like:

```
<SendPortRef Name="sndPortNameSpecified" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a reference to BizTalk.System application in your BizTalk App. You can check it by right clicking on yr app and references. If it's not them add it and then import the binding